# Springboot - spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra-reactive using custom Cassandra Driver version

Tags: java, spring-boot, cassandra

How to configure Springboot 2.4.2 to use the 4.10 Cassandra driver please?

Currently, a Springboot 2.4.2 will pull by default the spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra-reactive 2.4.2 version as well, which depends on the 4.9 version of the Cassandra driver.

I tried overriding at the pom level by importing the 4.10 Cassandra driver, but the app still starts with the 4.9 version.

```
.d.o.d.i.core.DefaultMavenCoordinates   : DataStax Java driver for Apache Cassandra(R) (com.datastax.oss:java-driver-core) version 4.9.0
```

How to configure Springboot 2.4.2 to use the 4.10 Cassandra driver please?

Thank you

Comment: Check `mvn dependency:tree` and exclude the dependency accordingly.

Comment: Could you share your pom.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using this configuration. You need to update your pom.xml with the new java-drive- core version 4.12.0. You can check this link to copy the dependency: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.oss/java-driver-core .

Somenting very important is to check the all the Compile Dependencies' version (18) that you use and update too. Update the maven dependency in your project. If it still show this message, you can delete the dependency fisically. If you are using the Eclipse's IDE, you can find the `...\.m2\repository` the respective java-drive-core 4.9.0 and delete it.

This version 4.12.0 have new features so nice. I recommend you use it.